# XML not referencing the XSD, namespacing issue

Tags: xml, xsd

This is driving me nuts. I am trying to create a schema for an xml document. I think I am pretty close but for some reason, I cannot figure out how to name the namespaces. Looked online at a dozen articles and tried everything but Visual Studio just doesn't seem to get it.

This is the xml file I want to create an XSD for:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<data xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="DataAutoNamespace dataautostructure.xsd" >
 <set id="HLM">
   <!-- Download page -->
   <item tag="Tabs" value="tabs"/>
   <item tag="HoldingsListTab" value="holdingsListTab"/>
   <item tag="BackLink" value="back"/>

   <!-- Holdings List Section -->
   <item tag="HoldingsList" value="holdingsList"/>
   <item tag="SubText" value="subText"/>
   <item tag="Format" value="format"/>
   <item tag="Contents" value="contents"/>
   <item tag="HoldingsFileName" value="fileName"/>
   <item tag="FileNameHeader" value="header"/>
   <item tag="Textbox" value="textbox"/>
   <item tag="InputBox" value="inputBox"/>
   <item tag="TextButton" value="textButton"/>
   <item tag="TextButton" value="textButton"/>

 </set>
</data>
```

And the schema that I have designed for this xml is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="DataAutoNamespace" xmlns="DataAutoNamespace" elementFormDefault="qualified">
  <xs:element name="item" type="itemType">
        <xs:unique name="UniqueItem">
            <xs:selector xpath="set/item"/>
            <xs:field xpath="@tag"/>
        </xs:unique>
    </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="data">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:all>
      <xs:element name="set" type ="setType"></xs:element>
      </xs:all>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
    <xs:complexType name="itemType">
        <xs:attribute name="tag" type="xs:token" use="required"/>
        <xs:attribute name="value" type="xs:token" use="required"/>
    </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="setType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element ref="item" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Can someone please guide as to what could be wrong with the namespacing? I am getting 'Could not find schema information for the attribute 'tag'.' and so on for 'id and 'value'.

Also, when I check inbound references to the schema, I don't get any. I want to make sure the tag attributes are unique within the XML.

Thanks, to all in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For a start you are declaring your elements to be in `DataAutoNamespace` but in your actual document there are no elements from that namespace to be found. You need to declare your namespace (& bind it to some namespace prefix) in your XML document with `xmlns`.

Comment: oh, I see. Is it not possible to validate without the prefix? I mean what if I remove the namespace DataAutoNamespace from the schema?

Comment: You could use `xmlns="DataAutoNamespace"` on your root element of the XML data?